# Steering Wheel Controls no longer function on JVC Stereo after reset

Tags: hyundai, audio

I have a 2015 Hyundai i25 (not bragging, just stating the facts) with a JVC Stereo (model KW-V21BT). After doing a soft reset the media controls on the steering wheel no longer work. There is a setting to map the controls under "Settings":"Steering Remote Controller" with the options "Set" and "Initialize" but the entire line is greyed out.

I have tried doing another reset and even unplugging the battery but neither one had any effect.

I am hoping that I don't have to try to remove the radio and play with the cables. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

If this is an aftermarket head unit, you'd have needed an adapter to allow the steering wheel controls to operate the head unit. Your reset could have caused it to reset either to the head unit or lose its connection with the controls. Either way, you'd need to figure out what type of adapter it is (it would be electronic) and then figure out how to re-pair with which ever side it lost its connection. There is just about no way we could tell you how to do either of those things with the information you've provided.

Comment: I bought the car used so I don't know if it's aftermarket or not. How would I check for an adapter? What is a "Head Unit"?

Comment: The head unit is what is in the dash (what you press buttons on and it plays the music). To my knowledge, Hyundai doesn't use JVC audio for their vehicles. I'm pretty sure what you have is aftermarket. You'd have to take the head unit out of the dash to find what is attached to it. It should be a small box attached to your head unit via wires. You may have to hunt for it a little bit. Then, once you find it, figure out who makes it so you can then get instructions for it. I'm suggesting yours might have this box because it's what I did to get the steering wheel controls to work on my Hyundai.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it and if it works I will mark your answer as "accepted".

Comment: I removed the head unit and detached then re-attached all the cables connecting it to the car. Still didn't help. Do you have an example of what the little box you are describing looks like?

Comment: @Lazer -  https://www.amazon.com/steering-wheel-control-interface/s?k=steering+wheel+control+interface